How, with tikzcd, to adjust the length of the lower arrow to cover the text beneath it?
Here is the code:
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=huge]
        \text{Es} 
        \arrow[r, shift left, "\text{IOU $R$}"] & 
        \text{Bs} \arrow[l, shift left, "\text{RRrrxxxttt worth 1}"] 
    \end{tikzcd}

The lower arrow is too short to cover the text "RRrrxxxttt worth 1". Also the text infringes into the positions of the two nodes (i.e Es and Bs).
I need to: elongate the lower arrow so it can exactly cover the text; and to move the positions of the two nodes accordingly. How can I do that?

column sep=3cm

It works. Thank you.

Not automatically, I'm afraid.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newlength{\tikzcdwidth}

\begin{document}

\[
\settowidth{\tikzcdwidth}{\scriptsize\quad RRrrxxxttt worth 1\quad}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=\the\tikzcdwidth]
  \text{Es}
  \arrow[r, shift left, "\text{IOU $R$}"] &
  \text{Bs} \arrow[l, shift left, "\text{RRrrxxxttt worth 1}"]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}


With a different approach, for the specific situation,
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\xrightleftarrows}[2]{% #1 = above, #2 = below
  \mathrel{%
    \vcenter{\offinterlineskip
      \ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr
        \quad$\scriptstyle\mathstrut #1$\quad\cr
        \rightarrowfill\cr
        \leftarrowfill\cr
        \quad$\scriptstyle\mathstrut #2$\quad\cr
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
\begin{document}

\[
\text{Es} \xrightleftarrows{\text{IOU $R$}}{\text{RRrrxxxttt worth 1}} \text{Bs}
\]

\end{document}



Thank you. It works beautifully.
